# How to Compare hash sub-keys

Tags: perl, hash, key

How to compare if 2 hash sub keys  match with eachother or not?

```
%hash={'Key1' => {
                   'Sub_key1' => [ 'value' ]
                 }
       'key2' => {
                   'Sub_key2' => [ 'value' ]
                 }
      }
```

Comment: Match how? Stringwise, numerically, case sensitively?

Comment: Also, you should probably work a bit harder on improving your indentation so that your code is more readable. Not just out of respect to the people helping you out, but for your own sake.

Comment: Stringwise, the way i have tried looks really stupid, im not sure it will be helpfull

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators), it will tell you all you need to know.

Comment: @Rocker - always add your attempt to the question, even if you think it's stupid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the hash you defined has not right syntax. It should be something like:

```
 %hash =('Key1' => {
                      'Sub_key1' => [ 'value' ]
                    },

          'key2' => {
                      'Sub_key2' => [ 'value' ]

                    }
 );
```

as you aren't using a hash reference (e.g. $hash ={....}).
Now, to iterate through the subkeys you have to do:

```
@array = ();
foreach $key ( keys %hash ){
   foreach $subkey (keys %{$hash{$key}}) {
       push(@array, $subkey);
   }
}
```

I used array because you might want to store more than two values in it and then compare them.Anyway, then you can do:

```
if ($array[0] eq $array[1]){
    print "Match";
}
```

as there are only two subkeys in your hash. If there going to be more, you should iterate through this array.